# julia vector differential equation: plot only the first n components of the vector

Tags: plot, julia, ode

I am integrating a vector differential equation in Julia (the number of components is of the order of magnitude of 50). When I plot this solution, obviously this plot will be very crowded if I plot all the components, so I want to plot only let's say the first 10 components. I can't find how to do this. Also, instead of plotting the output for each component, I would like to plot not the output of the integration at each time step, but the hyperbolic tangent of this. I also don't find how to do this manipulation. I think the key problem is that I don't understand/find what kind of object the solution of a differential equation is in julia.

Here is a minimal working example that integrates the differential equation and plots the whole solution.

```
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots
using LinearAlgebra

N=50                      
J=0.18*randn(Float64,N,N)   
g=1   

function hDerivative(timederiv,h,p,t)
    for i=1:length(h)
        timederiv[i] = -h[i]
        for j=1:length(h)
            timederiv[i]=+timederiv[i]+J[i,j]*tanh(g*h[j])            
        end

    end  
end

function pltTimeVolution()
    hinit=rand(Float64,N)
    tspan=(0.0,50)
    prob = ODEProblem(hDerivative,hinit,tspan)
    sol=solve(prob)

    plot(sol)  
    print(sol)

end

pltTimeVolution()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For help, take a look at the solution handling page: http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/basics/solution.html . The solution is both an abstract array and a continuous function. So you can for example get a continuous solution at 10000 evenly spaced time points like `t=range(tspan[1],stop=tspan[2],length=10000)`, do `A = sol(t)` and that will give a 50x10000 timeseries of each solution at evenly spaced time points, and then `sol[i,:]` would be the timeseries of the `i`th variable at the time points `t`. You can use that to build the arrays you want an plot them. Full code like this:

```
t=range(tspan[1],stop=tspan[2],length=10000)
A = sol(t)
ts10 = sol[10,:]
```

Another way to do this is to solve with something like `saveat=t`, in which case the solution is an array which saves at those time points. This looks like:

```
t=range(tspan[1],stop=tspan[2],length=10000)
sol=solve(prob,saveat=t)
ts10 = sol[10,:]
```

Or you can make use of the plot recipe which does this kind of handling internally. Take a look at http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/basics/plot.html#Choosing-Variables-1 . You can do things like plot the first variable and then lay over the plot of the 10th variable like:

```
plot(sol,vars=(0,1))
plot!(sol,vars=(0,10))
```

The `!` means its the mutating plot function, i.e. modify the previous plot by adding a new series. Then as noted in the documentation there are shortcuts, like

```
plot(sol,vars = [1, 3, 4])
```

will plot the 1st, 3rd, and 4th variables as functions of time. In this form, you can also specify what kind of transformation you want as a function. That's mentioned in the same place in the documentation. For example, the two-dimensional plot of time vs tanh would be the transformation function `f=(t,y)->(t,tanh(y))`, i.e. how you take in the 2D variable and spit out the 2D variable to plot is just pass through the first and `tanh` the second. Then using this, you'd use the plot command:

```
f=(t,y)->(t,tanh(y))
plot(sol,vars = (f,0,5))
```

to plot the `tanh` of the 5th variable against time.

These are a few different ways to manipulate the solution argument and generate the plots you need. Pick the one that works best for you.